# Pubnub subscribe in PHP

Tags: php, pubnub

I am using the Pubnub PHP SDK and subscribing to a channel like this:

```
$pubnub->subscribe(P_ROUTE_CHANNEL, function ($message) {
    return true; // Keep listening (return false to stop)
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/pubnub/php) `return true` should keep you subscribed. However, I find that at times the file just stops listening, I don't know why. I need a server side listener that always listen to a channel, and if for some reason it stops have something to trigger it to start again. What is the best way to do this?

I know I could have a cron job that checks the presence of the UUI and if it is not found trigger the file to run again but this seems a bit of a hack, is there a better way to do this within the Pubnub PHP SDK, not having to relay in an external check?

Answer (score 0):

Networking issues, such as disconnects, will manifest themselves as exceptions, so if you aren't catching and handling them, the loop will break. So be sure you are handling exceptions correctly.

If thats not the solution, please shoot an email to support@pubnub.com and we can assist you further through our official support channels.